# How to search for items in a table using the table sorter plugin-Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the tablesorter plugin and tablesorter widgets for searching through the items in a table. however i had a conflict with the tablesorterWidgets.js file while trying to set the number of rows per page.
js:

```
var $table = $("#table").tablesorter({
                         widgets: ['zebra', 'columns', 'filter'],
                         widthFixed : true,
                         ignoreCase: true,
                         widgetOptions : {
                            filter_columnFilters: false
                        }
 //used for searching specific items in the table
 $.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch( $table, $('input.search-sub-accounts'));
 items = $("table tbody tr");
                    perPage = 2;
                    numItems = items.length;
                    items.slice(perPage).hide();
```

However it never took the perPage number coz at some point in tablesorter widgets file, it overwrites the perPage number and resets it back to the original length of the items. 
is there any other way i could use to search the items from the input field.

http://jsfiddle.net/anLa1how/5/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm the example works? I'd love to help, however the fiddle linked is producing errors when run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the documentation, it looks like you have few issues.

### Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/h9z21sqz/) demonstrating the below fixes

---

#### Issue 1:

You are using [tablesorter.js Version 2.0.5b](https://rawgit.com/christianbach/tablesorter/master/jquery.tablesorter.js) with [tablesorter.widgets.js v2.23.3](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.23.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js)

You should instead use the newest version of each: [tablesorter.js v2.23.3](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js) and [tablesorter.widgets.js v2.23.3](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js)

---

#### Issue 2:

The [introduction](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#Introduction) states:

> tablesorter is a jQuery plugin for turning a standard HTML table **with THEAD and TBODY tags** into a sortable table without page refreshes. tablesorter can successfully parse and sort many types of data including linked data in a cell. It has many useful features including:

Your table does not have THEAD or TBODY tags which are required. If none are detected the tablesorter is not initialized and therefore the widgets cannot be created causing these errors to appear in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resizableNoSelect' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'widgetOptions' of undefined

---

#### Issue 3:

Per the [documentation for $.tablesorter.filter.bindSearch](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#function-bind-search)

> Include a data-column="#" attribute (where # is the column number) in the search input, to specify to which column the search should apply ~ see [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-external-inputs.html) for a full example. Warning!, if no data-column attribute is added to the input, the input will be ignored.
>
> In v2.15, use a data-column="all" to bind an external any-match search filter....

This means that where you have `<input class="search-items"/>` it should be more like `<input class="search-items" type="search" placeholder="Search" data-column="all">`  (change "all" to a column number if needed)

---

#### Issue 4:

As you mentioned, the `filter` widget seems to be overriding the pagination settings. A quick way to get around that would be to move the call to hide elements into the `onInit:` callback and put it inside a timer function so it lets the `filter` plugin do its thing first **then** hides the other "pages". Like this:

`setTimeout(function(){ items.hide().slice(startItem - 1, endItem).show();}, 100);`

This might not be the best way but without getting too deep into the widgets, this does work.

Comment: Thanks @DelightedD0D for sharing this info, but im baffled. when i click your fiddle it still shows 3 rows per page when perPage is set to 2. im i missing something...?

Comment: Ah, honestly, I forgot your original question when your fiddle didn't work at all. I'll look at it again in a little while

Comment: @user1234 see the update above and the updated jsFiddle. This works, however, if you havent already, you should take a look at [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) which is another plugin that offers everything you want all together and in my opinion is much more robust

Comment: awesome thanks so much @DelightedD0D for your effort!!

Comment: @DelightedD0Djust a quick thing i noticed. when i clear  the search input field, it again returns back to the original length of items...i.e perPage: 2 renders 2 rows as required, but when search field is cleared it will reset back to 3 rows...

Comment: is there any way I can still get it bak to 2 (or whatever number assigned to perPage)??Thanks!!!

Comment: @user1234 I looked into the reset bug, there seem to be ways to fix that but so far they all cause other unwanted behaviour without changing the original plugin code. I would suggest that you use the [pager plugin that was made for tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html) and just style the controls how you want them, or, use [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) which makes everything you need easy to do